# How to convert a html table to downloadable excel file ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net

I need a function to convert any HTML table to a excel file!

I like to add a button to my page and once that button is clicked I pass a complete HTML table in to such a function that will generate an excel file and past the html table into the file with the same layout and design!

I appreciate any help with this request.

I am using c# and asp.net

Comment: Try DataTable: http://www.datatables.net/

Comment: Try the following: save the HTML table to a file and give it the `.xls` extension. If the file has that extension it should open in Excel

Comment: Daniel, I am new to asp.net and c#. So i am not sure where to start! I have been Googling this for a while now and i am unable to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

This is a nasty trick, but it works in recent version of excel.

You just save the html table as a normal html file, then just rename it to xls. If your application is a web application use response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",  "attachment; filename=order.xls").

Recent version of excel support [Microsoft Office XML Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats), so if the previous solution doesn't work, you may want to try to generate the xml from the html table.
See [XML Spreadsheet Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28office.10%29.aspx).

What I do, is to generate the xml from excel in the xml format, then hack into it. You can implement also advanced features like automatic filters, and cool layouts. I used a template engine to generate the xml (Freemarker, it's Java stuff, but I'm sure there are template engines also for .NET)